# Acumatica and Unit Cost

Tags: acumatica

As background, we are very reliant on the serial items and every single serial item has it's own unit cost and price, etc...We are on 2017r2 for now.

We have had to overwrite the standard acumatica functionality that tries to pick up the stock items last cost to use that as it's unit cost fo that form/document. We have seen this on most documents in the inventory and distribution modules...

Anyway, we have realized that we missed a few spots and now we have a massive project to try and identify all of the items that were out of sync and correct them.

My questions/request for help is the following:

1) Is there any way to know all of the places that could effectively change what Acumatica has as the unit cost for a serial item? I know this happens on inventory receipts, purchase receipts, Adjustments, items that come out of the Manufacturing module, etc... Pretty much everywhere where it ends with a receipt of some sort i guess. I see this is also the case for inventory receipts on a two step transfer (This is the one that got us, we didn't realize that would happen).

2) Is there anyway on a more global level within Acumatica to have it automatically pick up the serial level unit cost as opposed to ever using the stock item cost statistics?

3) Does anyone have any ideas as to how to try and identify all of the possible items that may be effected, and how to resolve them once we identify them? Thankfully, we do have some custom fields that will hopefully have the correct unit cost, but we will still need to adjust these items back to their correct unit cost. But any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

I hope I explained the above clearly, and thank you in advance for anyone kind enough to help us out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the detailed explanation of the Item Costing in Acumatica by [this link](https://help-2017r2.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=d2036919-67cb-44ca-ab1d-c9d92ed52af7).
I think you can consider the generation of the Inventory Adjustment for all the Items with corresponding serial numbers, 0 quantity and fixed amount to correct all the costs without checking if the cost is correct or not. Please create backup snapshots before trying to generate such adjustments and check it on the test instance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I read this previously as well, and all our item classes were setup correctly to to be specific. however, that doesn't stop purchase receipts, and SO Returns receipts, etc from picking up the last cost of the stock item, as opposed to the unit cost of the item in question. Thinking out loud for a second. If Acumatica didn't have the serial number in the system prior, so this would be the first time it was coming in, would it default to the stock item last cost? or would it keep at 0 since it didn't have history of the serial item?

Comment: @Cory the system will default to average cost if I remember correctly